# Cannot load bcrypt on Windows 8.1 64-bit

Tags: node.js, electron, atom-editor, bcrypt

I make a sample ([electron-template](https://github.com/ledinhphuong/electron-template)) to use bcrypt. I install bcrypt without error by `npm install` command. It shows exception when I run electron-template.exe (Using `npm run build` to make it) every time:

[image: Exception every time]

P.s: This sample works fine on Mac 10.11

My environment:

> node 4.2.2
>   npm 2.14.7
>   bcrypt 0.8.5
>   Windows 8.1 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/

Version Compatibility -> highest supported version is 0.11.x.
Looks like they just not updated c++ extension to support node 4.x.
Since 4.x use new v8 this may cause troubles.

Ok, i just installed `bcrypt` via npm and successfully run samples with no issues.
node: v4.2.2, node-gyp: v2.0.0, Windows 10 x64

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
//async
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
  console.log(err, salt);
  bcrypt.hash('123', salt, function(err, res) {
    console.log(err, res);
  });
});

//sync, from electron
var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
var text = bcrypt.hashSync('123', salt);

console.log(salt, text);
```

result:

> $2a$10$GNsUyPsAcpalZRJAvnygG.
>   $2a$10$GNsUyPsAcpalZRJAvnygG.t/QEL2d2BcxK.pAPN13e3GI4mBta4V6
>
> undefined '$2a$10$bIWsjYdQoMU.GPrUacrca.' undefined
>   '$2a$10$bIWsjYdQoMU.GPrUacrca.m57OjFXqGje415c3r.9mfyTsCrx7Lu6'

The only thing that i can recommend to you is to verify that you have installed Visual c++ libraries. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/result.aspx?q=visual+c%2B%2B `Downloads` section. 
Install them, from 2012 to 2015. This helped me once with lwip module.

Comment: Also you should verify that you passing correct parameters when calling bcrypt module from node. Maybe they missed some arguments verifications inside c++ extension etc.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please recheck with the latest node-gyp 3.2.1?

Comment: Hmm, is there any chance that you have 32 bit version of node, or Visual Studio?

Comment: I installed nodejs 64-bit and VS 2013 Professional

Comment: Try to run 
`node-gyp rebuild --openssl-root="path to openssl"` from your project root (where package.json).

Answer (score 0):

its related with dependencies.

**bcrypt Dependencies**

1. NodeJS
2. node-gyp

   Please check the dependencies for this tool at: https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/

Windows users will need the options for c# and c++ installed with their visual studio instance.

3. Python 2.x
   OpenSSL -

   This is only required to build the bcrypt project if you are using versions <= 0.7.7. Otherwise, we're using the builtin node crypto bindings for seed data (which use the same OpenSSL code paths we were, but don't have the external dependency).

also check whether your gcc compiler is latest version

Comment: I have already installed necessary build tools. I can install bcrypt without issue:
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  bcrypt_lib.vcxproj -> d:\phuong\test-bcrypt\electron-template\node_modules\bc
  rypt\build\Release\\bcrypt_lib.node
bcrypt@0.8.5 node_modules\bcrypt
├── bindings@1.2.1
└── nan@2.0.5